Issues with Three-Finger and Four-Finger Gestures on Dell Inspiron 5402 (Ubuntu)
I recently installed Linux (Ubuntu) on my Dell Inspiron 5402, but I'm encountering problems with the multi-finger gestures. Specifically, the three-finger and four-finger gestures are not working as expected.
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Any guidance or recommended tools for gesture configuration would be appreciated.

You mention Ubuntu, but give no clues as to what Ubuntu product (Server? Core? Desktop?) and what release of that product.
